# .NET Client Application Services (Membership.GetUser())

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm using client application services in a WPF application.  Membership.GetUser() is not supported.  How do I get the current user?

Answer (score 0):

One of the following should work:

```
 System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

or

```
MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

or

```
Environment.UserName
```

Comment: Membership.GetUser() is not supported in Client Application Services.  The current pricipal is the Windows identity.  (Edit:  Apparently this will get you the username at least: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name)